# Google Maps iOs SDK - China

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, sdk

Actually i'm starting a project in China using Google Maps SDK for iOs and Android, i read the documentation and it says that the available URL in China is http://maps.google.cn, how can i configure it using the SDK.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommande you to use baidu maps or gao de, its more stable ( and who knows what can happen to google in futur in china! )

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using a WebView instead of the iOS SDK and using JS/HTML/HTTPS. The challenge then would be to communicate to the iOS native code from your WebView.